# Dealing with nulls when selecting in MyBatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have a query which at first launch returns zero rows:

```
<select id="getParams" parameterType="map" resultMap="ParamsResultMap">
    SELECT ID, GROUPS, TEMPLATES, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO
    FROM MY_FILTERS 
    WHERE ID = #{id}
</select>

<resultMap id="ParamsResultMap" type="my.domain.ParamsVO">
    <result column="ID" property="id"/>
    <result column="GROUPS" property="groups"/>
    <result column="TEMPLATES" property="templates"/>
    <result column="DATE_FROM" property="dateFrom" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP"/>
    <result column="DATE_TO" property="dateTo" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP"/>
</resultMap>
```

It is ok as I want to manage it in java:

```
ParamsVO params = myRepository.getParams(id);
if (params == null) {
    ...
}
```

But I am getting exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error setting null for parameter #4 with JdbcType OTHER . 
Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. 
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; 
SQL state [null]; error code [17004];
```

I've tried with `jdbcType = "DATE"` and without jdbcType with similar results.

My question is which is correct way to deal with queries which returns zero rows at MyBatis?

Comment: Which oracle database version did you use? And your DATE_FROM, DATE_TO fields are Date datatype or TIMESTAMP datatype?

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.4.0. Both fields are DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,

```
  <result column="DATE_TO" property="dateTo" jdbcType="DATE" javaType="java.util.Date"/>
```

And also need to check and update your JDBC jar file.Check the compatibility of ojdbc.jar [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) (I think you should need at least ojdbc6.jar) . For additional checking, If you have declared in your mybatis configuration xml file like this

```
<settings>
     <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="OTHER" />
</settings>
```

then change like that

```
<settings>
    <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL" />
</settings>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Still having the same exception. My jdbc is ojdbc14.jar and I don't have the settings you mentioned.

I don't have problems with dates when doing UPDATE or SELECT in the same project, only in this case when query returns zero rows. Maybe my approach is wrong and only way is to make new mapping for `select count(id) ... `?

Comment: Please update your jdbc jar. After that let me know ok or not.